# Calculating frequency of a motion

Tags: physics, classical-mechanics

I have the question

> A piston in a car engine executes simple harmonic motion. The acceleration $a$ of the piston is related to its displacement $X$ by: 
>   $$a = -6.4 \times 10^5X.$$
>   Calculate the frequency of the motion.

I know that frequency is $f = 1/T$. 
However I am not sure how to use the information given to find the frequency.

Comment: Use Newton's Second Law with this specific form for the acceleration and derive the frequency from it. Basically they give you the value of $\frac{k}{m}$. Look in here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_harmonic_motion for guidance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$ a = - \omega^2x $

Proof at : http://physicscatalyst.com/wave/shm_0.php (Look at the acceleration section)

Hence we know that

$ \omega^2 = 6.4 *10^5 $

$ \omega=800 $

and...

$$
\omega = 2\pi f
$$
$$
f = \frac {\omega}{2\pi} = 127.323954474
$$